# Como atribuir valores a um vetor?

Tags: matlab

Quero criar um vetor no matlab que receba 5 valores, a partir da variável 'tot'.

No meu programa tenho uma variável 'tot' que recebe 1/2

```
tot=1/2;
```

Quero que o vetor chamado de 'xi' na primeira posição receba o valor de 'tot'

Na segunda posição 'xi' receba tot+valor da primeira posição de 'xi'

Na terceira posição 'xi' receba tot+valor da segunda posição de 'xi'

Quero fazer isso para as 5 posições do vetor, só que de forma dinâmica, sem ter que atribuir os cinco valores do vetor um a um.

SEGUE ABAIXO O CÓDIGO QUE NÃO ESTÁ CERTO:

```
tot=1/2;

xi=(tot:tot)// a partir daqui não sei mais fazer

disp(xi)
```

Comment: Por favor, não utilize caixa alta em titulos.

Answer (score 0):

Neste caso, você não quer criar um vetor que receba 5 valores, mas sim criar um vetor com os 5 valores desejados.

Para usar a sintaxe parecida com o que você quer, o importante é ver como o [operador `:` (Colon)](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html#f1-85254) funciona e trabalhar com ele.

**Operador `:` :**

Quando você precisa de uma sequência, ele funciona de duas maneiras

```
a=1:3; %passo default (=1), saída > a=[1 2 3]  
a=1:2:3; %valor do passo selecionado , saída > a=[1 3]
```

Caso você precise de um passo negativo (mesmo se =1), é necessario declarar o passo:

```
a=3:-1:1; %valor do passo selecionado , saída > a=[3 2 1]
```

**No seu caso:**

Você tem duas opcões simples utilizando `:` :

```
tot=1/2;

xi=(1:5)*tot;

% OU

xi=tot:tot:(tot*5);

%ambos tem a mesma saída:
xi=
   0.5000    1.0000    1.5000    2.0000    2.5000
```